# Is there any alternate to implement 100-1000 "if...else" cases

Tags: java, c++, c

To implement a feature in my Project, I have to check 36 conditions.
For instance, assume First and Second are my Input variables. We can use 1-6 for First and Second.
If `First = 1` and will check the value of Second. If it is 2, then I will print as `First = 1` and `Second = 2`. If `Second is 3`, print as `First = 1` and `Second = 3` .....like this i need to implement `6 * 6 = 36` conditions.

I am using following logic

```
Switch(First)
Case 1:
     if(Second ==2)
     {
         print First =1 , second =2
     }
     else if ( Second == 3)
         print First = 1 And Second =3
         ......................

Case 2:
         ////// check all the remain 5 cases of Second value
case 3:
          ------------
.
.
.
.
case 6:
```

But I am not happy with the logic that I implemented, because if I have some 100-200 conditions, this is not good approach.

Any one, if you know any alternatives, please help

Thanks in Advance.

Regards,
Firoz

Comment: If you think you need to do that, you're almost certainly on the wrong track. Perhaps more information about what you're attempting might help -- and also, is this a Java, a C, or a C++ question? It can't be all at once -- what language are you actually using?

Comment: why not just `std::cout << "First = " << First << " Second = " << Second;`?

Comment: There is certainly an alternative, however the way you've phrased your question makes it impossible to answer.  Tell us about the real issue you're trying to solve and which of the 3 languages you tagged that you're actually using.

Comment: It depends upon what you want to do inside every condition. It should be generalized in such a way that Output = (some formula ) (first) (second).This may help your case.

Comment: You have "Java", "C++" and "C" tags, but your code looks like none of them. What language are you working in?

Comment: Based on what you've described it sounds like you can simply do: print First; print Second; done.

Comment: I think this question is salvageable, if you want to work on it a bit. Fix tags and describe the real problem. What input do you want to map to what output? Is there some pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You can put all the information in a table and write code to search the table for the result.

Comment: Yes.Use function pointer array . like this ---- typedef void (*FP)();  FP table[7][7];

Answer (score 0):

If 'first' and 'second' are both in the range 1-6, just switch on (first*10+second). Then case 11 means first=1, second=1; case 12 means first=1, second=2; case 21 means first=1, second=1; case 22 means first=2, second=2; etc.

Or if all you have to do is print a message, just make a message table indexed by [first][second].